# Вопрос по поводу редактирования файла в батнике

Tags: windows, циклы, bat

Допустим у меня есть 2 столбика данных  в файле

```
a  b
a    b 
a      b
a   b
```

И мне надо сделать вот так

```
a      b
a      b
a      b
a      b
```

То есть выровнять второй столбик ПО ПРАВОЙ СТОРОНЕ. Я думаю это надо через цикл добавлять пробелы с 7 элемента по 10, пока не появиться на 10 элементе сам элемент.

Comment: Используйте парсер for: **for /f "tokens=1"  %%a in ('вывод входных данных') do echo %%a        %%b**. В том случае, если строка **a** имеет переменную длину, используйте обработку строк для урезания её до необходимой длины.

Comment: @ Daemon строка а имеет переменную длину и урезать мне ее не надо

Comment: Хм, я имел в виду, что при переменной длине первого столбца - точнее строковой переменной - нужно увеличить её чуть больше требуемого размера ширины столбца с помощью пробелов. А затем отсечь лишние пробелы обработкой строк до фиксированной длины. Это один из способов выравнивания в батниках.

Comment: @ Daemon А как отсечь  лишние пробелы обработкой строк до фиксированной длины?

Comment: Предположим, требуемая ширина столбца 7 символов. Если переменная **А** имеет ненулевую длину, удлиняем её (переменную) пробелами в количестве 6 штук. А затем вырезаем 7 символов с начала строки и используем их. Получается выражение (где символ **_** обозначает пробел): **%A______:~0,7%**

Comment: @Daemon-5 У меня не получается выровнять второй столбик по правому боку.
'( for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (1.txt) do (
set "A=%%a                    "
set "B=          %%b" 
echo !A:~0,25!!B:~0,25!
) ) > t2.txt '

вот часть данных файла
**
fontdrvhost.exe                  3 116 
svchost.exe                        15 144 
svchost.exe                       7 384 
svchost.exe                        8 276 
svchost.exe                        5 548 
WtuSystemSupport.exe     8 316
svchost.exe                        111 540 **

Comment: Напишите команду формирующую данные, чтобы было понимание о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соберу комментарии в один ответ.
Предположим, что в качестве ввода информации используется вывод лог файла. В примере возьмем произвольный файл windows\DirectX.log.
Нужно пропарсить его и выровнять по второму столбцу. Причем ширина 1-го столбца составляет 11 символов.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('@type %windir%\DirectX.log') do (
set "A=%%a          "
set B=%%b
echo !A:~0,11!!B!
)
endlocal
```

P.S. обработку пустых строк оставляю на совести пользователей.

P.S.S. Если нужно добавить обработку 2-го столбца. То, соответственно,нужно оперировать переменной **B**.

Заменяем предпоследние строки:

```
set "B=%%b          "
echo !A:~0,11!!B:~0,11!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: теперь все работает